# Entity Framework робота с таблицами через разные контексты данных

Tags: .net, entity-framework

При разработке веб приложений если есть необходимость в системе аутентификации я использую ASP.net identity. Identity имеет свои таблицы в базе и свой контекст, ApplicationDbContext, для организации доступа к ним. Для доступа к остальным таблицам я создавал отдельный контекст.

Так я работал до сегодняшнего момента пока мне не понадобилось расширить таблицу AspNetUsers связав ее с другой таблицей. По этому поводу обнаружил материал в котором доступ к пользовательской таблице которая связывается с AspNetUsers организован тоже через контекст ApplicationDbContext.

Помогите разобраться в следующих вопросах:

1. Насколько плохо/хорошо/нейтрально использование разных контекстов доступа к разным таблицам в базе данных. Кроме того что для каждого контекста нужно создавать свою миграцию?
2. Можно ли организовать связи один к одному, один ко многим и многие ко многим для таблиц из разных контекстов и если да то чем это чревато?

Answer (score 1):

1. Использую для каждой группы таблиц свой контекст. В программе у меня больше 10 контекстов в итоге. Никаких проблем не возникает. На счет миграции - для каждого контекста нужна соответственно своя миграция. 
   Но есть один нюанс - если между собой контексты переплетаются(есть связи между таблицами в разных контекстах), то код миграции может дублироваться.
   Например, есть два контекста, таблица из второго контекста связана с таблицей из первого контекста. Если применить миграцию для этих контекстов, то вероятно, что код миграции таблицы из первого контекста будет как в коде миграции первого контекста, так и второго контекста(так как они связаны). Я не нашел, как это разруливать автоматически, поэтому просто дублирующий код миграции удаляю в одном из контекстов.
2. В первой вопросе уже ответил, связь таблиц из разных контекстов через навигационное свойство использую, никаких проблем в этом не вижу, кроме нюансов с миграцией.